# Can vet / veterinary bills be considered deductions (tax-deductible) for Income Tax purposes [Canada]?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-deduction

When I gathered all my 2009 receipts in preparation for my Income Tax filing, I came across a large number of expenses incurred for my pets.  Are these expenses tax-deductible?

Comment: Only if you claim them as dependents. =)

Comment: Well they don't exactly contribute to the household... ;-)

Comment: Sure they do!  Dogs and cats contribute to the security of house and home (when they want to). :-)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Medical bills for yourself or your human companions may be: [Canada Revenue](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns300-350/330/llwbl-eng.html)

Seeing-eye dogs and the like also get special treatment [Nice Doggie](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tp/it519r2-consolid/it519r2-consolid-e.html#P267_56490)

There are pet medical insurance policies; but as they are often priced like human policies, they might exclude your animal if it has a pre-existing condition.

Good Luck
Scott

Comment: I would expect that if the animal in question was part of your business (such as a farm animal, or a security dog) then you could probably claim vet bills as a business expense.

Answer (score 0):

In the US *service animals* are treated like durable medical equipment from a tax POV, and some expenses can be deducted. Likewise, expenses associated with working animals are business or hobby expenses than can be deducted to a certain extent.

But pets, no. Legally they are "chattels" -- property that can move. Generally speaking, you can't deduct the cost of maintaining your belongings.